# Using front end frameworks with a Wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, user-interface, web, wordpress-theming

I've been tasked with modifying the frond end of a Wordpress site, which is something I have not done before. I was first thinking of using Handlebars an Bootstrap, but I'm not even sure that will even work with the Wordpress framework.

If those don't work, what would be a good way to create a nice UI for the Wordpress site? Is creating my own theme a viable option? What tools am I even available to use?

Thank you.

Comment: There are plenty of themes that have Bootstrap integrated. You can make your own theme, get a starter theme, get a framework. WordPress is very flexible.

Comment: On the other hand: http://themeshaper.com/2014/08/19/why-bootstrap-is-a-bad-fit-for-wordpress-themes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of my favorite starter themes are:
http://themble.com/bones/ and http://underscores.me/

You can also look at frameworks like:
http://themeshaper.com/thematic/ or http://my.studiopress.com/themes/genesis/

I've used AngularJS with WordPress in the past, so I don't see why you wouldn't be able to use Handlebars (I haven't done it myself, but if you search, I'm sure you'll find some help there).

If you still want to use Bootstrap, there some tutorials on how to integrate it: http://digitalfellows.commons.gc.cuny.edu/2013/11/18/learn-bootstrap-part-2-adding-bootstrap-to-wordpress/